# Is there a difference between unaccessible and inaccessible

Tags: differences

Inaccessible is more common, but it seems that unaccessible is sometime used in the same places and it is listed in some online dictionaries.

Comment: Could you add the dictionary references you have found?

Comment: Purely a personal opinion, but to the extent that ***unaccessible*** could reasonably be used at all (and I might just spell it ***unaccessable*** anyway), I'd restrict it to IT-oriented ***data retrieval***. That's to say, ***information you can't access***, rather than the more common sense of ***place you can't get to***.

Comment: Are you asking *why* some words are less common than others? I don't think anybody can answer that.

Comment: The other day I was discussing "accessible" with another editor and noted that "handicapped-accessible" is often clipped to "accessible,"  and I asked whether people 50 or 100 years from now will read that and wonder what an accessible rest room was vs. an inaccessible one.

Comment: Context is everything!  The word choice may seem obvious from a logical reasoning standpoint. Inaccessible can imply that the object is difficult or next to impossible for anyone to access such as the deepest depth of the ocean called Challenger Deep. A way to look at inaccessible as closed off to public. It is not impossible or too difficult for authorized persons to get access to the same place such a a live crime scene that is taped off. Only special people can get in. If you are not special or authorized you have no access to that place. I would say there is a noticeable difference.

Comment: In cases like "accessible rest room", see definition #5 [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accessible): **easily used or accessed by people with disabilities** This is a modern narrowing of the traditional definition, much as "diverse" has come to mean "including minorities".

Answer (score 4):

Though listed in some [dictionaries](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Unaccessible), *unaccessible*  appears to be just an uncommon variant of *inaccessible*  as suggested by [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unaccessible%2C%20inaccessible&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunaccessible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinaccessible%3B%2Cc0) .

Note that:

> ***[Un-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/un-d)  is the most prolific of English prefixes, freely and widely used in Old English***, where it forms more than 1,000 compounds. ***It underwent a mass extinction in early Middle English***, but emerged with renewed vigor 16c. to form compounds with native and imported words. ***It disputes with Latin-derived cognate [in-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/in-#etymonline_v_6284) the right to form the negation of certain words*** (indigestable/undigestable, etc.), and ***though both might be deployed in cooperation to indicate shades of meaning (unfamous/infamous), typically they are not.***

(Etymonline)